# Vectorizing solve in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, symbolic-math

I have the following code:

```
syms y
x=linspace(0,1000,100);
b=solve((1/(x-y))-(1/y)=2,y)
```

and it does not work. I want to vectorize the solution but somehow I am missing something. I do not want to use a for to solve each value alone.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think how you would solve it using pen and paper. You wouldn't substitute x 100 times, then solve it 100 times. Instead solve it once for y, then put in the x-values:

```
syms x y
%use solve once
b=solve((1/(x-y))-(1/y)==2,y)
%generate anonymous function from the solution
c=matlabFunction(b)
%evaluate anonymous function 100 times
result=c(linspace(0,1000,100))
%to get only the highest solution
max(result)
```

It returns a 2x100 matrix because `solve` found two solutions.

Comment: Thanks so much. When defining c as the max value only, it returns "Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers." Thanks for abusing of your help.

Comment: What code did you use when you got the error? You can't use `max` for symbolic inputs, are you only interested in the positive solution?

Comment: I think now I understood your question. Apply `max` at the end to get the largest solution only: `max(c(linspace(0,1000,100)))`

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks.

Comment: Last question! If I want to run      ezplot('(1/(x-y))-(1/y)=2*p'), how can I make that matlab recognize p as an outside parameter?

Comment: The question is unclear to me, don't understand what you mean with an outside parameter. I recommend to ask a new question and explain what you want. Please also initialize all variables (like I just modified your question), knowing what variables are symbolic really simplifies reading the code.